# ¿cual es la manera correcta de escapar una exprecion regular?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Actualmente estoy trabajando con regex y utilizo una pagina para podre crear los patrones pero al pasarlo a javascript me arroja este error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Estoy trabando con la siguiente expresion regular

```
const regla1 = \([A-Za-z]+)(\W)([0-9]{1,9})(\W)+([0-9]{1,4})\g
```

Alguien me podria ayudar con la forma correcta de definir esta exprecion regular en una constante. Busco hacer replace en un conjunto de inputs donde se tiene que cumplir dicha regla.

Comment: Empieza y termina con / no con \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que cuando pones el caracter `\` estas haciendo un escape de caracer, debes usar en su lugar `/`

```js
function validate() {
  const str = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  console.log(str);
  const regex = /([A-Za-z]+)(\W)([0-9]{1,9})(\W)+([0-9]{1,4})/g;

  let m;

  while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // Tpara evitar ciclos infinitos
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // Al resultado se puede acceder con la variable m
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
      console.log(`Se encontro coincidencia, grupo ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" value="" hola-1-2 "" />
<button onclick="validate()">validar</button>
```